# Add clients current locatio to Google map but only if it is within the bounds of marker array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have built a database driven map application as an asp.net module within a CMS. We have multiple categories of maps (Schools, car parks , local attractions, recyling sites etc etc) each with their own custom markers.
We center and locate the map using map.fitbounds(latLngBound) according to the array of categories selected.

All works great but is it possible to add a users current location to the map **but** only if it is within a specific boundry i,e a city centre or the map.fitbounds(latLngBound)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LatLngBounds` class has a `contains` method that allows you to check if a `LatLng` is within the given bounds.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds

Where `userLocationLatLng` would be your user location as a [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) object:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

if (bounds.contains(userLocationLatLng)) {
  // Do something
}
```